# Printing an image to bluetooth

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, printing, bluetooth

Am currently printing base64 image to bluetooth but it instead returns things like special characters. Am using srehanuddin Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer.
Any ideas?